# Can vim command history store commands that produce an error?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm new to vim (for the seventh time) so this may not be something that makes sense for vim style but:
The command history in the command window has up-arrow mapped to history and this has been very helpful in learning, except that it does not seem to store commands that fail to execute in the history.  Obviously, this is a bad configuration choice for someone trying to learn from mistakes.  Is there a way to force it to remember the failed commands, in the sense that they can be recalled with the up-arrow?

FYI, I am using MacVim with Janus extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of error are you talking about? `:s/foo/bar` is always recorded into history, even if there was no `foo` on the current line and you get E486.

---

As a side note, if you use Ex commands a lot you might be interested in the Command line window, invoked by `q:`, that you can navigate and *edit* just like any other window. It's really great.

Also, drop Janus as soon as possible! That pile of crap is the absolute worst thing to install when learning to use Vim. **Seriously.**

Comment: I had gotten MacVim into a state where it needed to be restarted.  I didn't expect that to affect command history but I probably should have.  I'm on day three of my ninth time trying to get into vim and I'm just learning that restarting is a big part.  

My previous eight attempts at learning vim, I insisted on a plain install (no plugins).  I never made it past two days.  I think Janus is the only reason I'm still trying (even if I'm not yet sold).  Are you recommending a different distro for learning?

Comment: I recommend plain Vim and no distro whatsoever. That's the *only* way to learn Vim properly. Do you want to learn Janus or do you want to learn Vim? The main promise of distros is to allow new users to be "productive" faster but it comes at a high price: you don't get control of your environment. The key is to learn Vim *on the side*: keep using your usual editor until you are ready to switch. It's simple, it's easy and it works..